# Google Embed Api Shows White Boxes Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: javascript, analytics

Tasked with a project integrating Google Analytics to charts via the Embed API. I cannot get the demo *on the Google site* to load, all it shows is white boxes, see attached "embed-api-demo.jpg:"

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/interactive-charts/

Similar questions on S.O. relate to developers not getting *their* code to work - this issue is loading the demo *from the Google site.*

My environment and tested in:

Ubuntu 18.04 (Unity)

FireFox 65.0 64 bit

Chrome (Chromium) 72.0.3626.96

No special filtering or blocking in the browsers and have conferred with colleagues on Mac and Windows, it loads fine for them. A second Ubuntu user on Mint/Gnome has confirmed, also white boxes.

If it turns out to be an issue with the O.S. I could probably install VirtualBox and struggle through with Windows, but would prefer not to do that (and guessing it should load regardless of platform.)

I have worked with G.A. and the embed API extensively but it has been a few years and a lot has changed, presume I'm starting from scratch.

The debug console reports different errors in FF vs. Chrome. I have not yet dug into a browser setting that may be interfering with loading the demo, that is my next step.

FireFox:

```
CSI/tbsd_ cb=gapi.loaded_0:620:127
CSI/_tbnd cb=gapi.loaded_0:620:127
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Object { error: {…} }
cb=gapi.loaded_0:106:97
uncaught exception: [object Object]
```

Chrome (Chromium:) The "opened" error details are quite long but here is the version with the details closed. Saving the log doesn't show this information. see attached "chrome-error-console.jpg."

```
-> GET https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries?max-results=0&_src=embed-api%3Av1 403 cb=gapi.loaded_0:149
-> {error: {..}} cb=gapi.loaded_0:106
-> Uncaught -> {error{...}} cb=gapi.loaded_0:76
-> [Deprecation] chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated, instead use standardized API: Paint Timing. https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5637885046816768. common.js:25
```

Thank you for any pointers/direction anyone can provide.

[embed-api-demo.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6UUS.jpg)

[chrome-error-console.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2tkQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Marking solved. What is not clear from the demos is that they only display data linked to *your* account. You must be logged in to G.A. to see the demos.

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me at this point, if I am a site owner and want to show my visitor a graph of stats, they shouldn't need a G.A. account to see them.